# Custom GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am thinking of a way to implement a view using RecyclerView like this image where the header row is on the left side and the content under that header on the right.[image] Any ideas or pointers on how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone else gets here looking for an answer/ solution, here's what I did. I used default GridLayoutManager using child RecyclerView in the parent RecyclerView. Parent RV is using GridLayoutManager while child RV uses LinearLayoutManager. For parent RV, using multiple viewType, position 0 or position %2 == 0 returns HEADER_TYPE while the rest returns CARD_TYPE. Using this

```
mGridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 3)
        mGridLayoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
                return when (enquiryAdapter.getItemViewType(position)) {
                    HEADER_TYPE -> 1
                    CARD_TYPE -> 2
                    else -> -1
                }
            }
        }
        recyclerView.layoutManager = mGridLayoutManager
```

I changed the spanSize. For position that returns CARD_TYPE, I inflate another RV which takes list to layout the content view. I am not sure this is the best solution but that seems to be working for me. I will gladly accept any solution working better/simpler than this.